# manipulations with elements of vector and structure C++

Tags: c++

For understanding more difficult processes and operations with vectors, I've decided to make a very simple example. So, I have vector, it has structure type. Structure, in its turn, has 3 array: `a`, `b`, `c`. I fill them, and then try to print elements of first array in the structure. But I do something wrong and don't know what exactly, maybe everything. Here is the code:

```
using namespace std;

struct hl {
    int a [3];
    int b [3];
    int c [3];
};

int main()
{
  vector<hl> vec;
  struct hl he;

  for (int i = 0; i!=3; ++i) {
      int aa = 12;
      int bb = 13;
      int cc = 14;

      he.a[i]= aa+i;
      cout <<"Hello.a["<< i << "]=  "<<he.a[i]<<endl;
      he.b[i]= bb+i;
      he.c[i]= cc+i;
  }

  for (std::vector<hl>::iterator it = vec.begin() ; it != vec.end(); ++it) {
    //print arr.a[n]
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use a [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), it's more terse and expressive.

Comment: Assuming he uses C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the loop that fills the arrays of the structure add the following statement

```
vec.push_back( he );
```

and then you can output elements of the first array of the structure that is contained in the vector

```
for ( int x : vec[0].a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Or you could write

```
for ( const hl &he : vec )
{
   for ( int x : he.a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Or you could explicitly use iterators of the vector

```
for ( std::vector<h1>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it )
{
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( it->a ) / sizeof( *it->a ); i++ )
   {
      std::cout << it->a[i] << ' ';
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Instead of statement

```
for ( std::vector<h1>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it )
```

you couls also write

```
for ( auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
But I have a question. Can you explain this: sizeof( it->a ) / sizeof( *it->a ). Why do we use here sizeof ?

Comment: @user3856196 What is the question?

Comment: @user3856196 This expression determinates the number of elements in the array. sizeof( it->a ) returns the size of the entire array in bytes.  sizeof( *it->a ).  returns the size in bytes of an element of the array (in this case of the first element of the array). So you will get the total number of elements. Or you could use magic number 3 instead of the expression.:)

Comment: Hmm. May I ask you the last question? It`s about location of structure`s elements in the vector. After we do this: vec.push_back( he ) - we get an access to a, b, c arrays at the vec[0] level? So, if we do it --> vec.push_back( he ) once more - we`ll get a,b,c in the vec[1] and so on?

Comment: @user3856196 You are right. The vector behaves as an array with the dynamically modified size.

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding the element `he` to the vector.
You need to do

```
vec.push_back(he);
```

The iteration should look like that:

```
for(std::vector<hl>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->a[0] << ", " << it->a[1] << ", " << it->a[2] << std::endl;
}
```

Also, in C++ you don't need to prepend struct/class variable declaration with `struct` keyword. It's C style.
You just need:

```
hl he;
```

Comment: `h1` don't have a << output operator ;)

Comment: it was an answer in progress. :) updating.